# How to modify /etc/hosts file in iPhone program?

Tags: ios, iphone, jailbreak

Is it possible to modify /etc/hosts file in iPhone program?

How about for Jailbreaked iPhone?

How to do that? Do I need to call specific API? or just use file operations API.

Answer (score 2):

For a **non-jailbroken** app, the answer is **no**.

For a **jailbroken** app, you're no longer bound by Apple's sandbox, so you can interact with the system directly, for example via file operations (`fopen` and friends).

Comment: Even then, applications that are running on the phone do not have write access to the /etc/hosts file as the apps run as an ordinary user, while the /etc/hosts file is owned by root.

Comment: This is also my concern. Is it possible get the root permission in program? Or do I need to make use of the Cydia? I don't know. Any idea?

Comment: If you're using Cydia then an apt postinst script to `chmod +s` your binary should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

For a non-jailbroken phone the only way I managed to do this was to change the /etc/hosts file on the wireless router I was connecting to or use a custom DNS server that would in fact cause a DNS poisoning (this is illegal, afaik).